# Use JavaScript regex to capture all string values from VBA code

Tags: javascript, regex, vba

I want to use JavaScript regex to list all string values used in VBA code.

Example:

```
If cmd = "History Report" Then
     Range("D2").Formula = "=TEXT(""" & createDate & """,""" & Replace(subtitleFormat, """", """""") & """)"
     comment = "This task is completed!"
End If
```

The result will be:

```
1> "History Report"
2> "D2"
3> "=TEXT("""
4> ""","""
5> """"
6> """"""
7> """)"
8> "This task is completed!"
```

I'm so glad to have some better ideas to solve this problem.

Comment: You can't use JavaScript regex in VBA. You can use the *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* library to use VBScript-flavor regex though.

Answer (score 2):

```
""*[^"]*"*"
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pG1kU1/19

Edited:

```
"(?:"{2})*[^"]*(?:"{2})*"
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pG1kU1/23

Comment: @ZuZu Please mark vks' solution as the answer if it worked for what you needed.

Comment: I have fixed a mistake with example. In VBA, string value can contain double quote by double up on the quotes. I want to capture whole string that can contains double quote such as: "I need ""your help"" in this problem".

Comment: @ZuZu: I have a regex solution that will correctly deal with the VBA string literals.

Answer (score 1):

You need to account for double quotation marks inside string literals:

```
"((?:""|[^"])*)"
```

This will match all them. Capturing group 1 will hold the strings themselves. If you want quotes to be part of your results, just use `"(?:""|[^"])*"`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vQ1yN1/1).

[Another "unrolled" regex](https://regex101.com/r/zR2iA6/1) for this task:

```
"((?:[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*))"
```

Comment: Unrolled version is  43% faster than the one with alternatives.